# Spring Mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

> Hi, i written the simple  hello world Spring example.How can i access
>   the this into WSO2 ESB Spring mediator,and **is there any changes i
>   have to do in repository of WSo2 ESB**, i follow the
>
> http://charith.wickramaarachchi.org/2009/01/apache-synapse-spring-mediator-feel.html.
>
> from this link , i didn't get  Synapse home in WSo2 ESB. Can any one
>   give working example for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i am working on WSO2 ESB 4.7.0,
I follow   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762090/working-example-on-spring-mediator-in-wso2-esb-4-6-0/19835951?noredirect=1#comment29535564_19835951) one , my ESB with Spring mediator,now it's  working fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check the available [spring sample](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+470%3a+How+to+Initialize+and+use+a+Spring+Bean+as+a+Mediator);

[1](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+470%3a+How+to+Initialize+and+use+a+Spring+Bean+as+a+Mediator)http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Spring+Mediator