# Working example on Spring Mediator in WSO2 ESB 4.6.0

Tags: spring, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Hi i am working on Spring Mediator in WSO2 ESB 4.6.0, using [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+470%3a+How+to+Initialize+and+use+a+Spring+Bean+as+a+Mediator) and [this](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Spring+Mediator) tutorial

I am getting the Error as follows:

```
ERROR - SpringMediator Cannot look up Spring configuration conf/sample/resources/spring/springsample.xml

ERROR - SpringMediatorCannot reference application context with key : conf/sample/resources/spring/springsample.xml
```

Could you please explain me how to solve this.

Comment: You get this error when running the sample application or are you working on your own thing?

Comment: Hi Isuru,First thank you for your replay..While i am running the sample application,which given by Wso2 ESB Documents sample, Can you tell me how can i achieve this..

Comment: I try the sample and work fine in wso2esb 4.6. Did you build the axis2 sample correctly?

Comment: HI Isuru, this my Spring Proxy service, <spring:spring xmlns:spring="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" bean="springexample " key="conf/sample/resources/spring/springsample.xml"/> ,here i am directly using sample spring example, i didn't not build any axis2  sample..could you please explain me.How to do this..

Comment: I updated the answer have a look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got to work this as below,

The class should extends AbstractMediator and override the mediate() method as follows,

```
package com.test.spring.mediator.workingexampleonspringmediator;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class HelloWorld extends AbstractMediator{

           private String message;   
       public void setMessage(String message){
          this.message  = message;
       }

       public boolean mediate(MessageContext arg0) {

          System.out.println("HELLO "+message);
          return true;
    }
}
```

Then place the jar in [ESBHOME]/repository/components/lib folder

In mediate method it prints a message with the argument like `HELLO 'arg'`

And I added the following file to registry `(/_system/config/repository/spring/springtest.xml)`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC  "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
        "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd"> 
<beans>     
   <bean id="springtest" class="com.test.spring.mediator.workingexampleonspringmediator.HelloWorld"  singleton="false">
   <property name="message"><value>ISURU</value></property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

My proxy is as follows,

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testSpring" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="START" value="__________________________"/>
         </log>
         <spring:spring xmlns:spring="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" bean="springtest" key="conf:/repository/spring/springtest.xml"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="END" value="______________________"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

In the proxy you can see the `bean=[bean id of the springtest.xml]` and `class=qualified name of the class`

In my ESB terminal, I got the following out put with the given property value in springtest.xml,

```
[2013-11-07 17:38:30,654]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/testSpring.testSpringHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:bcae82e9-4027-43c5-bd7a-cbfa885aaf33, Direction: request, START = __________________________, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
HELLO ISURU
[2013-11-07 17:38:30,692]  INFO - LogMediator To: /services/testSpring.testSpringHttpSoap12Endpoint, WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:bcae82e9-4027-43c5-bd7a-cbfa885aaf33, Direction: request, END = ______________________, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

You must restart the ESB after placing the jar in repository/components/lib

Comment: more details here `http://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/wso2-spring-mediator-example/`

Comment: oh, its fine. what I have done is I have added a collection and then upload the file there. Therefore you no need to add spring folder just upload it there and it should work. The blog[1] I mentioned above is not having the spring folder.
[1]http://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/wso2-spring-mediator-example/

Comment: @Kanchetianeel http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html
Follow the above link up to step 5. Then you should get an idea how to upload a resource (xml file) to registry.

Comment: HI ISURU,Great thankful to you  for your patience and your amazing talent, It's working , your are really extraordinary ..

Answer (score 2):

These are the steps for spring mediator in brief  as Isuru explained above

1. Create spring mediator library by extending AbstractMediator
2. Copy into ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib
3. Re-start the server
4. Register springtest.xml file in the Registry
   (http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html up to step 5 as Isuru explained)
5. Then, create a Custom proxy with Spring Mediator.

In there,
add  Bean  as “springtest” (defined bean id for the mediator class within the xml file)

Select the Key as where  the configuration registry file stored  according to the 4th step.

Ex : If you have stored that springtest.xml file into path “_system/config/repository/”
Select Key as “/_system/config/repository/springtest.xml”

**Note:**

- Verify in ESB_HOME/repository/components/dropins folder for OSGI
  bundle of the mediator of the created spring mediator library which
  is copied into ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib. If it is not there
  after restarting server, it may be a problem in created mediator
  library.
- As well as, put unique package name for the mediator class to avoid
  conflicts with other mediator class in
  ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib.
- Keep in mind to add unique bean id for the .xml file which is
  registered in the registry when you registered .xml file in 4th step.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the esb finds the `springsample.xml` file in the path `repository/conf/sample/resources`

```
<parameter name="root">file:repository/conf/sample/resources/</parameter>
```

But the `springsample.xml` file location is in `repository/samples/resources/` . Therefore it should be corrected as the following,

```
<parameter name="root">file:repository/samples/resources/</parameter>
```

In documentation, the configuration is not correct, If you start the esb by the command `wso2esb-samples -sn 470` (as mentioned in the documentation) the esb will load the file in `repository/samples/synapse_sample_470.xml` where in this file above parameter is correctly configured.

Hope this will solve your problem :)

UPDATED:

According to your comment, as your are directly using sample spring example, this occur due to permission of the file trying to access, Or this can be due to file path error. So please try with absolute file url.

Comment: @Kanchetianeel Where's the bean classes I couldn't find it on git hub

Comment: Hi Isuru ,Thank you , here it is my git Hub url :-https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7351959   could you please checkme..i am getting the sample problem..

Comment: @Kanchetianeel I added another answer with full details. Mark it as the answer if you find that it is correct

Answer (score 0):

when i send a message, the only error message i got is this one

```
ERROR - SpringMediator No bean named 'springtest' is defined
```

so it means, the config file has been found. But what about the instanciation of the bean inside, i cannot see any explicit error. The jar file is in components/lib and i can see it also in dropins folder.

:/

Comment: Spring logs are not redirected to the console so i cannot see that my jar export has failed. It was an instanciation problem on unexisting class in Spring